# Two MIME type in NFC tag in Android

Tags: android, nfc, mime-types, ndef

Can we add two MIME types in NFC tag while writing. I.e., I want to add two package names to MIME type. Actually I want to launch any one of the two application while reading the NFC tag from outside the app whichever application is installed.

Comment: Yes you can, however you need to add a special filter in the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write whatever information you want to a tag. MIME type records can contain any data (that fits the MIME type). You can also have multiple records on one tag.

Regarding your question of starting two different apps with one tag, you could simply use a URI record and have both apps contain an intent filter for that URI (so both apps share one URI). No need for different records here.